# Validating DatetimeFields in SharePoint 2010 List Form PreSaveAction Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, newform

I want to perform a validation for today's date and user entered date in my custom list form's multiple datetime fields

ReqstRecvdDate Field

DueByDate field

ReqstRecvdDate can not be greater than today's date.It can be equal to today's date or less than today's date.

if RecvdDate>=Today , I need to prevent user from saving the form- `presaveaction` call.

Also DueByDate field, which has to be greater than ReqstRecvdDate Field.
I added the  below code, but the validation is not working when

a) I selected 31-Oct-2015 as ReqstRecvdDate & I selected DueByDate field as
01-Dec-2015. As per the rule it's set to true and should  allow me to save the form, but this didn't happen.

```
       <script language="javascript" 
       src="/project/EASAssetsLib/jquery-1.6.0.min.js" 
       type="text/javascript"></script><script language="javascript" 
         src="/project/EASAssetsLib/jquery.SPServices-
        2014.01.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script 
     language="javascript" 
        src="/project/EASAssetsLib/prototype.js" 
       type="text/javascript"></script><script language="javascript" 
       src="/project/EASAssetsLib/SPUtility.js" 
       type="text/javascript"></script><script language="javascript" 
        type="text/javascript">

     function PreSaveAction()
      {
       var reqstrecvddatethrusputility = SPUtility.GetSPField('Request 
       Received Date').GetValue(); 
      var reqsteDateStr=reqstrecvddatethrusputility.toString();
      var mon1  = reqsteDateStr.substring(0,2); 
       var dt1 = reqsteDateStr.substring(3,5); 
       var yr1  = reqsteDateStr.substring(6,10);  
       temp1 = mon1 + "/" + dt1 + "/" + yr1;
       var dtReqstRecvdDate = new Date(temp1);
       var reqstRecvdDateInUTC = dtReqstRecvdDate.toUTCString();
        var currentTime = new Date();
       var CurDateInUTC = currentTime.toUTCString();
      dt3 = new Date(reqstRecvdDateInUTC);
      dt4 = new Date(CurDateInUTC);
   if(dt3 > dt4 )
     {
       alert('Received Date cannot be greater than Todays  
               Date!');
       return false;
     }
```

Due to some reason,month range is not getting  recognized properly.

What I need to change in my code to do the right validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing String operations on Dates is never a good habit.

You are adding so many libraries allready.
Adding [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/) to make date calculations a breeze won't be an issue..

Your Month problem is probably because **in JavaScript january === 0 , thus december === 11**

Comment: I downloaded the moment.js into my assets lib.How to use it with dates which is coming from SharePoint datefield?

Comment: I got the date format value like this:                                                                     var reqstrecvddate2 = SPUtility.GetSPField('Request Received Date').GetValue();  
 var duebydate2 = SPUtility.GetSPField('Due By').GetValue();
 var reqstrecvddate2moment = moment(reqstrecvddate2).format("MM/DD/YYYY"); 
alert(reqstrecvddate2moment + ' ...from moment' );                                  But how to compare the reqstrecvddate2 against duebydate2moment ?

Comment: You are taking too many steps at once. First play with/learn JavaScript date calculations, then make it work in SharePoint. Your problem is not SharePoint. Your problem is you do not understand working with JavaScript dates.

Comment: Agreed!.Let me work on that and revert.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/7-code-playgrounds/

Comment: Danny,Your guidance on the moment.js file saved my time and gave me the correct validation! Thanks a lot!